# Why isn't this saving to the database, excel import

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save the excel import data into the database, currently the routes and everything is working, it's just not adding anything to the database. It goes into the function `import` but nothing happens, the problem is almost definitely in the code in that function but I'm not sure how it should go instead.

This is my code in the controller

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('test');
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    Log::info($path);
    $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
    Log::info($data);

    if ($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $arr[] = [
                'NOMBRE' => $value->name,
                'CEDULA' => $value->card,
                'CARNET' => $value->scard,
                'TIPO-USUARIO' => $value->user_type_id,
                'CORREO' => $value->email,
                'PASSWORD' => $value->password,
            ];
        }

        if (!empty($arr)) {
            User::insert($arr);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/imports');
}
```

When I run the only thing in the logs is `local.INFO: test` which is the first line in the function but everything after that is blank, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should add your fields in the [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) property in order to be able to insert the records that way

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['NOMBRE','CEDULA','CARNET','TIPO-USUARIO','PASSWORD','CORREO'];
}
```

Also maybe you may to move your insert statement into the for statement like this in order to insert the current processing user into the database or cycle the $arr and insert it after

```
if (!empty($arr)) {
            User::create($arr[$key]);
        }
```

Comment: they are bypassing eloquent by calling `insert` which only exists on Query Builder, which is why they can pass many records

Answer (score 0):

you can doit like this if you are using laravel

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('test');
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    Log::info($path);
    $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
    Log::info($data);

    if ($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $user = new User();
            $user->NOMBRE = $value->name;
            $user->CEDULA = $value->card;
            $user->CARNET = $value->scard;
            $user->TIPO-USUARIO = $value->user_type_id;
            $user->CORREO = $value->email;
            $user->PASSWORD = $value->password;
            $user->save();
        }
    }`enter code here`
    return redirect('/imports');
}
```

Comment: You should also include an explanation of the solution, like what you have changed and why. That way, more people with similar issues can take advantage of your answer.

Comment: Why doesn't the OP's log file get the $path dumped?